# JavaScript compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, compatibility

I've done a lot of research but can not find a code to make a script compatible across all browsers. I would like this function to work in Firefox, IE, Chrome, etc but at the moment, it only works in Chrome and Older than Firefox version 49. Any help is greatly appreciated. Code is below:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(tag) {
            var x = document.getElementsByName(tag)[0];
            var a = x.parentNode
            if (a.style.display == 'block') {
                a.style.display = 'none'
            } else {
                a.style.display = 'block'
            }
        }


        function init() {
            //this function will add show hide functionality to paired list items,
            //as long as the answer is a list item straight after the question list item.
            //You can also have as many separate lists as you want.
            //all lists must be contained within a div with id QA

            var obj = document.getElementById('QA');
            var elements = obj.getElementsByTagName('li');
            var index = 1
            //add javascript to question elements
            //you could also add styling to question elements here
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 2) {
                var element = elements[i];
                element.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:toggle(" + index + ")'>" + element.innerHTML + "</a>"
                index = index + 1
            }
            //add bookmark to answer elements and add styling
            var index = 1
            for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i += 2) {
                var element = elements[i];
                element.innerHTML = "<a name='" + index + "' id='" + index + "'></a>" + element.innerHTML
                index = index + 1
                element.style.padding = '0px 0px 10px 20px' //add indent to answer
                element.style.listStyleType = 'none' //remove bullet
                element.style.display = 'none' //hide answer element
            }
        }

        window.onload = init;
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: where are you calling this toggle method

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: another thing dont use <a href='javascript:toggle(" + index + ")'> it better have it on onclick or somehting

Comment: One way to get cross-browser compatibility is to use a library like jQuery.

Comment: This code is all in the head. The rest of the code is in the body: 

<div id="QA">
<ul>
<li>Question 1</li>
<li>Answer 1</li>
<li>Question 2</li>
<li>Answer 2</li>
 </ul>
<ul>
<li>Question 3</li>
<li>Answer 3</li>
<li>Question 4</li>
<li>Answer 4</li>
 </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>

Comment: J08691 -> I'm not getting an error, The question should be a link to the answer in the <li> so when you click the question, the answer appears, click it again it disappears. Right now, the question and answer all appear without the hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your body, `Document.getElementsByName()` may behave differently between the different browsers:

> The `getElementsByName` method works differently in different browsers. In IE & Opera, `getElementsByName()` method will also return elements that have an id attribute with the specified value. so you should be careful not to use the same string as both a name and an ID.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Comment: You can use them both if they're on the *same* element, e.g. `<input name="foo" id="foo" type="text">` should be OK.